# Can Muslims take part in human genomic editing for disease treatment?

Tags: halal-haram

I am taking a class in which I am able to choose a scientific topic to explore. I want to explore potential HIV-1 treatment via human genome editing. My goal is to help cure/treat HIV. I don't want to fundamentally change what a human is from birth (such as changing their gender) because from my understanding that would be considered trying to "improve" on Allah's creation (which I am NOT trying to do and is obviously very wrong to do).

From some searches, I found that, in general, humans are allowed to find solutions to harms. However, I want a specific, definitive answer to this type of question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t improve on Allah’s creation.  Here’s why.  Allah created you. If you can find a way to edited your genome to advance yourself and or society then his creation lead to its own self improvement.

That action by itself is due to Allah's creation.   Your brain is his creation.

To be honest I am surprised to hear this as a question.  Helping the world.  How could that possibly be haram.  Especially when there’s practically zero harm to anyone.

Changing gender, on the other hand, is not considered an improvement. Unless you are sexist and you believe one gender is better than the other.